# Asking about interview traveling arrangements

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I'm currently interviewing for a startup and I made it to the onsite. I'm wondering if this is an okay way of asking for traveling arrangements since financially it is difficult for me:

> I'm currently located in Chicago, so flying on short notice might be a bit expensive on my end. I'm curious if there's a possibility of traveling arrangements?

I know this might be a bad question but this job means a lot and any form of feedback is helpful.

Comment: Did you ask upfront about the location concerns? Did anyone calling you mention the distance? Did you include your address on your resume/CV or application? It would be wise to let them, as soon as possible, know you live a distance away and have to fly out to meet them. Most companies will not help in relocation and don't want non local candidates....it is best to find out so you don't waste their time.

Comment: I did and we discussed it before as well. Turns out they just forgot.

Comment: You discussed it an they forgot.   What is it they forgot?

Comment: @kermitvomit they forgot a candidate lives a considerable distance away, so much so that he must fly out to commute there? Perhaps you might not want to work for this company if they are that absent minded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's a fine and professional way to ask it.  Another would be to just pretend like it's expected, and say something like, "I'm really looking forward to the upcoming interview. Do you have a preferred travel agent or system that I should use to book my tickets and hotel, or just use my own and submit receipts for reimbursement?"

I don't know about startups, but most "normal" companies pay for onsite interview travel as a matter of course.

Comment: Startups can do anything, you have to be careful. But normal procedure is this.

Comment: Right, and if nothing else the way I worded the question will make them feel like they're wrong to say, "we don't do that". :)