# Should I ask the company I'm interviewing with pay for my travel expenses?

Tags: interviewing

I'm based in France. If it costs me 30 or 40 euros to get across the country for an interview, is it the job of the company I'm interviewing with to cover that?

Comment: Just ask them. "Do you reimburse travel costs?"

Comment: Also: [Asking about interview traveling arrangements.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70296/asking-about-interview-traveling-arrangements?rq=1) [Should I ask for travel expenses for an interview after not being offered a job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91390/should-i-ask-for-travel-expenses-for-an-interview-after-not-being-offered-a-job?rq=1) [How do companies usually cover travel expenses for final onsite interviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40331/how-do-companies-usually-cover-travel-expenses-for-final-onsite-interviews?rq=1)

Comment: Depends also on local law, e.g. in Germany companies are required to reimburse travel expenses for interviews. In any case just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they've been upfront with offering to reimburse you, I'd say that they won't.

Most of the time, interviewees have to fund their own way to interviews unless there's special circumstances (i.e. a flight/overnight stay is required).

Here in the UK, it would cost me about the same to travel into London for an interview - I wouldn't even think to ask for that cost to be paid back; I'd assume it might be taken as a negative if I demanded travel costs.

If anything, you could say something in the interview if they ask how the journey was - don't mention the cost, just the length of the journey and see if anything is offered.

I wouldn't outright ask, but that might just be me.

Comment: Maybe it's a difference across different countries, as in several other questions on this site people mentioned that it's quite normal to ask and sometimes even for the company to directly offer to pay everything, especially for non-entry-level positions. It seems that in Europe it is quite less common than in the US. Anyways don't think it would hurt much to ask politely when accepting the interview though.

Comment: Also in Germany it's actually required by law for the hiring company to reimburse travel costs for interviews.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects of this situation.

**Is there any mention of travel expense reimbursement in your interview call letter?**

If no, then most probably they won't reimburse it. Every company have a different policy regarding reimbursement.

**Should you ask for it?**

If it is not mentioned in the call letter, then you can ask the contact person if there is any provision for it before travelling. However, I won't recommend you to mention it during your interview.